# How to start audio player on tapping play button in UNUserNotification action button while app is inactive?

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer, uilocalnotification, unusernotificationcenter

Hi I have an audio player app which has a timer section.The objective is to make audio start / stop at a specific date and time. I have implemented this using  `UNUserNotificationCenter`.This is working fine when app is in foreground.But when app is **inactive/ background** , the player will play only if the app is opened and brought to foreground.Can anybody help me with this.

```
     func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
}
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    print("Local notification received")

    let application = UIApplication.shared
    print(response.notification.request.content)

    let identifier = response.actionIdentifier
    let request = response.notification.request

    if(identifier == "StartPlaying")
    {
        AudioManager.sharedInstance.setAudioPlayer(audioUrl: "http://athmaraksha.org/admin/uploads/audio/040D-Daivathinte Vagdhanangal-329.mp3", fromAudio: true)
        AudioManager.sharedInstance.player?.play()


    }
    else if(identifier == "StopPlaying")
    {
        AudioManager.sharedInstance.player?.pause()

    }

    completionHandler()


}
```

Comment: I think activating a `.mixWithOthers` `AVAudioSession` will make this work.

Answer (score 0):

There are certainly multiple ways to do it. One way that I prefer, and is quite easy, is to use a Global singleton.

So the problem is handling the data from the push notification while having your app restarted from the background, right?

In the `func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)` method, that's where we handle the push notifications, right?

I have a way there to check if I can push or present a screen currently (e.g. the app is fully opened, and not restarting from the background). If there's not a way to push or present a screen, because the app is just restarting from the background (meaning, no screens are presented yet to the user), then I would save a data to that global singleton that I've mentioned above.

And when the root or home screen just got fully loaded, that means we're ready to check if there's a saved data from the push notification, and that's when we're ready to do any UI changes or presentation/pushing of screens based on the push notification.

I hope this idea helps!